# Linq returning unexpected results

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have the following query which should return no rows, but returns 4:

```
var testAgainst = db.MyForm1_hosps.Select(ta => ta.recordId == recordId);
```

If I use the following query I get zero rows as expected:

```
var testAgainst = from ta in db.MyForm1_hosps
                  where ta.recordId == recordId
                  select ta;
```

There ARE four rows in MyForm1_hosp but none match the recordId in my test.

The code doesn't lie, so my understanding of LINQ is incorrect. Can someone explain to me why the first one returns 4 rows when it should return 0?

Comment: `db.MyForm1_hosps.Where(ta => ta.recordId == recordId);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first query has a mistake. Change the `Select` to `Where`.

```
var testAgainst = db.MyForm1_hosps.Where(ta => ta.recordId == recordId);
```

Investigating your original query with `Select(ta => ta.recordId == recordId)`: This will return a sequence of *booleans*. If none of the records in `db.MyForm1_hosps` have `recordId` values matching the input, the results will all be false. If you have 4 records, you will get 4 false values. You have 4 results, but they are not of the type you think they are!

Comment: derp derp, that is what i get for using a method based solely on its name. thanks for the explanation and change suggestion.